# How to know when an external JS has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to execute specific JavaScript instructions AFTER an external JavaScript finishes its own process.

```
(function(){
    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
    dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = 'http://xxxxxxxx.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

How can jQuery know when that .js has finished doing what it does?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method can load script files even from [external domains](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4a2/src/ajax.js#L279), and you can provide a callback function, that will be executed when if the script is loaded successfully:

```
$.getScript('http://xxxxxxxx.disqus.com/embed.js', function () {
  // specific instructions here...
  alert('Script loaded!');
});
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/evuha3).

Comment: hi... the problem is that embed.js execute specific things and that doesn't happen immediately. It takes around 3 seconds for the script to complete its processes, but the alert triggers sooner than that =( -- any ideas?